# The EntityFramework package is not installed on project when Add Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am getting the following error despite I have installed EntityFramework.

> PM> Add-Migration Initial
>
> The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'Common.Persistence'.

Can someone help me sort this ?

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="2.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Common.Models\Common.Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: How many projects do you have in your solution?

Comment: have around 4 projects

Comment: Please read [ask] and try searching before asking a new question. If you did search, show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

In package manager console make sure you are selecting the correct project where you need to do the migrations.